# How work correctly with GoogleCloudMessaging and FacebookSDK in same project

Tags: android, facebook, google-play-services, facebook-sdk-3.0, google-cloud-messaging

I'm working  with google cloud message in a android project, for this reason  I am importing the   google play services library but in my project  also I need import the facebookSDK library, my problem is that the project  not work when  I have including the google play services library  and facebookSDK library 
What is  the correct form for import these libraries 
I think that G.C.M not work fine, it is because the Facebook SDK project has  for default the google play services library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding Java Build Path reference to android_sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\libs\google_play_services.jar file will fix the issue

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try what you recommend